# Laravel cashier subscription on custom model - cancel subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I am trying to use my own custom model in laravel for creating subscription using cashier. some how i made it working, but when i try to cancel the subscirption i am getting the below error.below is the code i am using to cancel the subscription and error it throws

My code

```
$profile = Profile::where('userid', $userid)->first();
//print_r($profile);exit;
$cancel = $profile->subscription('DailyPlan')->cancel();
```

Error

```
Call to a member function stripe() on null
```

and it point out to below function on laravel cashier package

```
public function updateStripeSubscription(array $options = [])
    {
        // print_r($options);exit;
        // print_r($this->stripe_id);exit;

        return $this->owner->stripe()->subscriptions->update(
            $this->stripe_id, $options
        );
    }
```

i am not sure what i need to make it working

Comment: $profile->subscription('default')->cancel()   if the the has only one subscription

Comment: Instead of default in using my plan name here , still no luck

Comment: you should get user first not profile like User::where('userid', $userid)->first(); bcz cashier use user model

Comment: then  $user->subscription('default')->cancel()

Comment: I am not using the user model

Comment: you also create subscription with this profile model?